# how can I set contentoffset and change the height of UIScrollview at same time

Tags: keyboard, uiscrollview

I'm trying to scroll up my `UISCrollView` when the keyboard is shown

I use setContentOffset to shift the uiview up.

At the same time I want to decrease the height of my `UISCrollView` to (view height - keyboard height), so that the entire content view can be scrolled.

I apply both the changes in keyboardWillShow notification

When I actually bring the keyboard up in my app, the contents first get pushed up and then they are pushed down (which gives a flickering effect). I'm trying to smooth out both the transformations in one go..

Is it possible?

Code Below ---

```
- (void) keyboardWillShow {
   CGPoint contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset;

    CGRect scrollViewFrame = scrollView.frame;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];

    if (contentOffset.y >= 0 && contentOffset.x >= 0) {
        isContentOffset = YES;
        contentOffset.y += screenShift;
        [scrollView setContentOffset:contentOffset animated: NO];
    }

    scrollViewFrame.size.height = keyboardOrigin.y - self.view.frame.origin.y - toolbarHeight;
    scrollView.frame = scrollViewFrame;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is an option for animation when you setContentOffset for animation. here is the code that i use all the time

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    svos = scrollView.contentOffset;
    CGRect rect = [textView bounds];
    rect = [textView convertRect:rect toView:self.scrollView];
    CGPoint point = rect.origin ;
    point.x = 0 ;
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:point animated:YES];
    doneButton.enabled = YES;
}

- (IBAction)donePressed
{
    [scrollView setContentOffset:svos animated:YES]; 
    [textview resignFirstResponder];
    doneButton.enabled = NO;
}
```

It works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Are you wrapping these changes in an animation block?

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"resizeScroll" context:nil];
// make your changes to set and content offset
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: yes and I tried setContentOffset with animated On and Off, it still gives the same effect

Answer (score 0):

I think I have got a solution for this. You can handle the resize of the view in `textViewDidBeginEditing` method. You can just change the frame size of the scrollView to half by

```
CGRect tframe = myscrollView.frame;
tframe.size.height/=2;
myscrollView.frame = tframe;
```

and to initialize or handle the total length of the scrollview you can set the contentSize of the scrollView in the similar fashion as the frame was set in above snippet. for example

```
CGSize tsize = self.view.frame.size;
//here you can change the height and width of the scrollView
myscrollView.contentSize = tsize;
```

I hope this should do the trick for you. If it does please communicate.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue...

When the keyboard button was clicked, I was doing a becomeFirstResponder followed by a resignFirstResponder on keyboard view. This caused keyboardWillShow followed by keyboardWillHide and another keyboardWillShow notification, which brought the keyboard up, brought it back down and then up again.

Thanks to everybody who tried to help out.. and sorry the issue was pretty different...